# How to get another section of my url php using $_GET

Tags: php

I have the following url coming back like

```
questions.php?n=1a=1
```

Now in my code I have

```
$number = (int)$_GET['n'];
$answerwrong = (int)$_GET["a"];
```

What I cannot understand is I am getting `$number` fine each time, but `$answerwrong` has the following error

> Notice: Undefined index: a in C:\\questions.php on line 8.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: That's because the url itself is wrong, it should be `questions.php?n=1&a=1`

Comment: your url indicates parameter n holds the value 1a=1, you need to have a separator '&' for  each query string you pass..

Answer (score 1):

In particular, when a form containing the fields `field1`, `field2`, `field3` is submitted, the content of the fields is encoded as a query string as follows:

`field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3...`

The query string is composed of a series of field-value pairs. Within each pair, the field name and value are separated by an equals sign, `=`.
The series of pairs is separated by the ampersand, `&`.

So, your URL must look like `questions.php?n=1&a=1`

Answer (score 0):

> You can join n number of arguments by adding `&` middle of two parameters (ex `id=007&name=JamesBond`)

So URL should be

```
<a href="URL/questions.php?n=1&a=1">Click me</a>
```

and this both will work

```
$number = (int)$_GET['n'];
$answerwrong = (int)$_GET["a"];
```